# Does divide-and-conquer really win against the increased memory allocation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory-management, divide-and-conquer

I've just finished coding some classical divide-and-conquer algorithms, and I came up the following question:(more for curiosity)

Admittedly, in many cases, divide-and-conquer algorithm is faster than the traditional algorithm; for examples, in Fast Fourier Transform, it improves the complexity from N^2 to Nlog2N. However, through coding, I found out that, because of "dividing", we have more subproblems, which means we have to create more containers and allocate more memories on the subproblem additionally. Just think about this, in merge sort, we have to create left and right array in each recursion, and in Fast Fourier Transform, we have to create odd and even array in each recursion. This means, we have to allocate more memories during the algorithm.

So, my question is, in reality, such as in C++, does algorithms like divide-and-conquer really win, when we also have to increase the complexity in memory allocation? (Or memory allocation won't take run time at all, and it's cost is zero?)

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: In many cases, reducing the time a function takes to operate requires a comparable increase in memory usage.  You can reduce the time a prime-finding algorithm takes by storing many primes in memory, for example.

Comment: In programming you often have to choose between fast or slim on resources, you very seldom can pick both. (And unfortunately it's very easy to find programs where none of the alternatives was picked.)

Comment: Not all divide and conquer approaches require more memory, in many cases the operations can be done in place. Admittedly there are cases where extra memory is either required or desired (you can do the merge step in mergesort without acquiring additional memory, but performance will be worse.

Comment: Memory allocation does take some time however you have to look at this on a case by case bases.

Comment: There are results in complexity theory that give trade-offs for certain problems. For example, one important result states that deciding the satisfiability of a boolean formula cannot be done in both linear time and logarithmic space; you need more of at least one of them and by doing so may be able to use less of the other resource.

Comment: My sense is that the extra time taken for memory allocation using divide-and-conquer algorithms is negligible, but I have nothing to base that on. There is, however, one sure way to find out: benchmarking. Go ahead and code FFT or merge sort using both approaches, generate a reasonable number of test cases of different input sizes and time your algorithms.

Comment: @beaker I agree with the advice to benchmark. However, it is worth noting that it is very important to measure the largest supported problem size, and remeasure as sizes increase with time. An algorithm with higher complexity but lower constant multiplier may win for many problem sizes, but be useless for the largest sizes. As a naive young programmer in the 1970's, I was told that a particular function only had to support up to 200 input cards. I checked that a sequential search was faster than the card reader up to 500 cards, so I kept it simple. Bad choice for thousands of cards.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Agreed. That was what I was trying to get at with my description of "reasonable" test cases, but it's definitely worth pointing out *why* a range of input sizes is necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Almost everything when it comes to optimisation is a compromise between one resource vs. another - in traditional engineering it's typically "cost vs. material".

In computing, it's often "time vs. memory usage" that is the compromise.

I don't think there is one simple answer to your actual question - it really depends on the algorithm - and in real life, this may lead to compromise solutions where a problem is divided into smaller pieces, but not ALL the way down to the minimal size, only "until it's no longer efficient to divide it".

Memory allocation isn't a zero-cost operation, if we are talking about `new` and `delete`. Stack memory is near zero cost once the actual stack memory has been populated with physical memory by the OS - it's at most one extra instruction on most architectures to make some space on the stack, and sometimes one extra instruction at exit to give the memory back.

The real answer is, as nearly always when it comes to performance, to benchmark the different solutions.

Answer (score 5):

It is useful to understand that getting "one level better" in big-O terms (like going from n^2 to n, or from n to log n) usually matters a lot. Consider your Fourier example.

At `O(n^2)`, with a `n=100` you're looking at `10000`, and with `n=1000` you get a whole million, `1000000`. On the other hand, with `O(n*log(n))` you get `664` for `n=100` and `9965` at `n=1000`. The slower growth should be obvious.

Of course memory allocation costs resources, as does some other code necessary in divide-and-conquer, such as combining the parts. But the whole idea is that the overhead from extra allocations and such is far, far smaller than the extra time that would be needed for a small algorithm.

The time for extra allocations isn't usually a concern, but the memory use itself can be. That is one of the fundamental programming tradeoffs. You have to choose between speed and memory usage. Sometimes you can afford the extra memory to  get faster results, sometimes you must save all the memory. This is one of the reasons why there's no 'ultimate algorithm' for many problems. Say, mergesort is great, running in `O(n * log(n))` even in the worst-case scenario, but it needs extra memory. Unless you use the in-place version, which then runs slower. Or maybe you know your data is likely already near-sorted and then something like smoothsort suits you better.

Comment: Though one always needs to keep in mind that asymptotic bounds on computational complexity (big Oh and friends) aren't functions of n, they're infinite sets of functions of n. They hide constants and factors which don't dominate, gloss over implementation details, are rarely used to count time but rather some abstract "operation", and so on. To compare two algorithms with complexities `O(f(n))` and `O(g(n))`, you can't just take `f(n)`, `g(n)` and plug in values for `n`. See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/112872/7043 for some elaboration.

Comment: @delnan And if we're on the topic of big-O pitfalls anyway, it's important to remember that `O(n)` denotes the upper bound and is often used to also express the average complexity. For many algorithms it is important to distinguish between best, worst and average scenarios. Also, the "constant dropping" can sometimes be misleading. A `O(n^2)` algorithm will be better than a `O(n)` which really is `O(1000000*n)` for "small" data sizes - and sometimes all your data is "small".